# json-schema with additional properties of type x and at least one

Tags: jsonschema

**Question:**

Is there a way to tell the json-schema that I want additional properties of type x and at least one?

**short explanation** (based on the code-block below):

I want to have a json-file with one required item, *a*.
*b* is optional and I need minimum one additional item.
The name of the additional item has to be flexible.
For that reason I'm not able to give it a specific name and mark it as required.
And because *b* is optional, I'm not able to use 'minProperties'

something like: (doesn't exist)

```
"additionalProperties": {
    "type": "string",
    "minAdditionalProperties": 1
  }
```

**unfinished json-schema**

```json
{
 "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
        "type": "number"
    },
    "b": {
        "type": "number" 
    }
  },
  "required": ["a"],
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

**expected result:**

b is always optional

```
invalid:
{
    "a": 1
}
----
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
}

valid:
{
    "a": 1,
    "x": "2"
}
----
{
    "a": 1,
    "x1": "2",
    "x2": "4"  
}
```

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And because b is optional, I'm not able to use 'minProperties'

Why not? Surely `minProperties: 2` will get you what you need: 'a' is required, so one additional property is needed.

If you want one additional property in addition to the optional property 'b', then you can use an `if`/`then`/`else`:

```
  "if": {
    "required": [ "b" ]
  },
  "then": {
    "minProperties": 3
  }
  "else": {
    "minProperties": 2
  }
```